# Why does setting padding:0 on <div> gives different result than setting it on <p>?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

```css
#example {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="example">paragraph line 1<br>
 paragraph line 2<br>
 paragraph line 3<br>
 paragraph line 4</p>
</div>
```

This will result to the paragraph having 0 padding top and bottom. However, if I put the `id="example"` on the div like this,

```css
#example {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <p>paragraph line 1<br>
 paragraph line 2<br>
 paragraph line 3<br>
 paragraph line 4</p>
</div>
```

it will result with the paragraph having padding on the top and bottom. Why does it yield different result despite declaring both `id="example"` a padding of `padding:0;`?

Comment: are you sure you talking about the `padding` and not about the `margin`? Both your examples [here in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1vfkjbo/) I don't see any different behavior with padding

Answer (score 1):

You can always use reset css before building your website here's a great reference here [Reset Css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) so that each tags are set to default.

also add in your reset css

```
*,*:before,*:after {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

to not allow paddings or margins give extra spaces when you add them in a tag element.  This way you can have more freedom of your own styling for adding margins or paddings in your style.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default margin in html elements unless you remove it yourself. When a new container is added, in your case p tag, there is default margin. So to remove your problem you can use code as:

`*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

this gets styled in every element in html and removes default padding and margin. Hope this solves your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change margin with padding css.

tag has margin inside in the div.Set margin zero to remove it.

```css
p {
  display: block;
  margin:0;
}

#example {
   border:1px solid black;
   padding:0;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="example">
  <p>paragraph line 1<br>
     paragraph l2ine 2<br>
     paragraph line 3<br>
     paragraph line 4</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple because **HTML Paragraph** tag has default margin this is define in the [Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) and that value are different for different Browser.

That is the reason of using [Universall CSS Reset](https://cssreset.com/scripts/universal-selector-css-reset/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

which reset ***padding** and **margin** for every HTML tags

Otherwhise the `div` Tag Element doesn't have any default padding or magin for all Browser.

So when you apply the selector `#example` to `p` and `div` tag It's completly normal to have different behaviour as long has the `p` tags has a default margin and padding depending with browser used.

To avoir that missbehaviour you can rely on the **Univeral CSS Reset**

Answer (score 0):

Because each element has different default values. Take a look:

```
p {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

div {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your problem is that in this code:

```css
#example {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <p>paragraph line 1<br>
 paragraph line 2<br>
 paragraph line 3<br>
 paragraph line 4</p>
</div>
```

...you have space left above and below the paragraph.

You'd think that's the `<div>`'s padding, however, that's actually the `<p>`'s default margin.

You can see this by setting the `<p>`'s `margin` to 0:

```css
#example {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
}

#example2{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <p id="example2">paragraph line 1<br>
 paragraph line 2<br>
 paragraph line 3<br>
 paragraph line 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. So the `<div>` `padding:0;` doesn't overwrite the default padding of `<p>`?

Comment: It's a **margin**! They both create spaces, but margins are *outside* the element and padding *inside* the element. That space was taken up by the `<p>` element, so, **no**.